# This is the response getting from a server. I am trying get value of an atribute Folio ID. How can we get using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am getting below response from server and want extract attribute value from it. When I am using simplexml_load_string and DOMDocument it gives only  PersonName & HKStatus outout.

**XML**

```
<OTA_ResRetrieveRS EchoToken="a" TimeStamp="2022-02-10T18:49:29+05:30" Version="0.0" Target="Test" xmlns="http://www.example.com/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/OTA/2003/05 OTA_ResRetrieveRS.xsd">
  <Success/>
  <ReservationsList>
   <HotelReservation ResStatus="In-house" RoomStayReservation="true" WalkInIndicator="true" CreatorID="roommaster:17.10">
    <RoomStays>
     <RoomStay MarketCode="UNK" SourceOfBusiness="WALK">
      <RoomTypes>
       <RoomType IsRoom="true" RoomTypeCode="KNG" RoomID="100"/>
      </RoomTypes>
      <RatePlans>
       <RatePlan RatePlanCode="RACK"/>
      </RatePlans>
      <GuestCounts>
       <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="10" Count="1"/>
      </GuestCounts>
      <TimeSpan Start="2022-02-10" End="2022-02-14"/>
     </RoomStay>
    </RoomStays>
    <ResGuests>
     <ResGuest PrimaryIndicator="true">
      <Profiles>
       <ProfileInfo>
        <UniqueID Type="10" ID="100000" ID_Context="roommaster"/>
        <Profile>
         <Customer>
          <PersonName>
          <NamePrefix>Mr</NamePrefix>
          <GivenName>Sanya</GivenName>
          <Surname>Raj</Surname>
          </PersonName>
         </Customer>
        </Profile>
       </ProfileInfo>
      </Profiles>
     </ResGuest>
    </ResGuests>
    <ResGlobalInfo>
     <Guarantee GuaranteeCode="CASH">
      <GuaranteesAccepted>
       <GuaranteeAccepted GuaranteeIndicator="true" PaymentTransactionTypeCode="CASH" GuaranteeTypeCode="1"/>
      </GuaranteesAccepted>
     </Guarantee>
     <HotelReservationIDs>
      <HotelReservationID ResID_Type="10" ResID_Value="100000-A" ResID_Source="roommaster" ResID_SourceContext="Master Folio"/>
     </HotelReservationIDs>
    </ResGlobalInfo>
    <TPA_Extensions>
     <HTNG>
      <ProfileMessageSummary Text="0"/>
     <HKStatus>Occupied</HKStatus>
     </HTNG>
     <Folios>
      <Folio ID="100000-A" Description="Master Folio" Balance="0"/>
     </Folios>
    </TPA_Extensions>
   </HotelReservation>
  </ReservationsList>
 </OTA_ResRetrieveRS>
```

**PHP**

```
$bcdoc = new DOMDocument();
$bcdoc->loadXML($xml);
$warning = $bcdoc->getElementsByTagName('Warnings')->item(0);
        
if(empty($warning)){
    $FolioID = $bcdoc->getElementsByTagName('Folio')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $FoliaID."\n";
            
}else{
    $warning = $bcdoc->getElementsByTagName('Warnings')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $warning."\n";
}
```

Only PersonName and HKstatus get output. I have used simplexml also to extract atribute but same result. What is the function can be used to extract attributes? Any idea how can I get value of Folio ID? In above example it is 100000-A.

Comment: Could you edit this post to add the console output that you _do_ get?

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `getAttribute`, but because `getElementsByTagName` returns an array, you will either need to get the first item or loop through the list if you have multiple folios.

```
$bcdoc = new DOMDocument();
$bcdoc->loadXML($xml);
$warning = $bcdoc->getElementsByTagName('Warnings')->item(0);

if (empty($warning)) {
  $FolioID  = $bcdoc->getElementsByTagName('Folio')[0]->getAttribute('ID');
  echo $FolioID . "\n";
} else {
  $warning = $bcdoc->getElementsByTagName('Warnings')->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo $warning . "\n";
}
```